# Magento 2: Not able to duplicate the product from admin

Tags: product, magento2.3.2, duplicate

I am using Magento 2.3.2 and I am trying to duplicate one of existing SKU from admin I clicked on save and edit and I am getting the following issue.

```
The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.
To resolve this conflict, you can either change the value of the URL Key field (located in the Search Engine Optimization section) to a unique value or change the Request Path fields in all locations listed below:

- all-items/chip-dip-14-3-4.html

- colorwave-serving-pieces/chip-dip-14-3-4.html

- entertain-with-colorwave/chip-dip-14-3-4.html
```

Answer (score 1):

**URL Key** of the product is made by SKU by default, you can duplicate the SKU but not the **URL key** so where you are trying to duplicate the SKU try to manually set the **URL key** of the respected product[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create simple module to fix this like below

> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/CatalogUrlRewrite/Model/ProductUrlPathGenerator.php

```
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model;

    class ProductUrlPathGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator
    {
        /**
         * Ignore attribute url_path. Always use url_key instead.
         *
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function getUrlPath($product, $category = null)
        {
            $path = $product->getUrlKey()
                ? $this->prepareProductUrlKey($product)
                : $this->prepareProductDefaultUrlKey($product);
            return $category === null
                ? $path
                : $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category) . '/' . $path;
        }
    }
```

> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator"
                type="<VENDOR>\<MODULE>\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator" />
</config>
```

reference 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12412

Comment: this code is not working same issue is there. Note i checked code is going into rewrite function

Comment: this code is not working with me. Can anyone have solution to help me?